# Why is it possible to use one class to inherit constructors from another class in Typescript

Tags: arrays, typescript, nestjs

why this is not Person（class）but is a Persson(constructor)
Why is it possible to use one class to inherit constructors from another class in Typescript?

```
function Name(constructor: Function) {// ！！！！！ why this is not Person（class）but is a Persson(constructor)
  return class Name extends constructor {
    name = 'genal';
  }
}


@Name
class Person {
  constructor() {
    this.type = 'yellow';
  }
}

console.log(new Person());

outPut：Name{ type: 'yellow', name: 'genal' }
// ！！！！！ why this is not Person（class）but is a Persson(constructor) in Function Name
```

Comment: The expression for the class decorator will be called as a function at runtime, with the constructor of the decorated class as its only argument. 
https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/decorators.html

Comment: The class syntax is mostly syntactic sugar over the normal constructor functions. At runtime `Person` is *a function*. And more precisely it's the constructor for the Person class.

Comment: you mean Person ===  Persson(constructor) ？@VLAZ

Comment: Yes. There is no "class" at runtime, it's a function. Hence why you can call it: `new Person()`. The class syntax helps with defining that function.

Answer (score 1):

This is not TypeScript specific, it is related to how JavaScript works. Classes are just functions.

Classes are a new feature that are part of the ECMAScript 6 standard (from 2015). It's mostly just syntactic sugar for an established JavaScript pattern for emulating classes. The following code:

```js
class MyClass {
  constructor(myProp) {
    this.myProp = myProp;
  }
  
  print() {
    console.log(this.myProp);
  }
}
```

does almost the same thing as this:

```js
function MyClass(myProp) {
  this.myProp = myProp;
}

MyClass.prototype.print = function () {
  console.log(this.myProp);
};
```

As you can see, JavaScript classes are just functions! But what does it mean and how does it work?

The answer is this: Every time you call a JS function, a hidden `this` parameter is passed to the function:

- When you call a function by itself (`myFunction()`), `this` is the global object (usually `window` on browsers).
- When you call a function with the dot notation (`myObject.myFunction()`), `this` is set to your object (`myObject`).
- When you call a function with the `new` keyword (`new myFunction()`), a new object is created and `this` is set to this new object.

There is one more thing: the prototype. In JS objects have a property called the prototype. When you use the dot notation, if the object doesn't have the requested property, it's looked up in the prototype. If it can't be found there, it's looked up in the prototype's prototype and so on. The `new func()` syntax sets the newly created object's prototype to `func.prototype`. So when you write:

```js
var myObject = new MyClass("propValue");
myObject.print();
```

the `print` method is looked up in `myObject` and since it isn't there, it's looked up in `MyClass.prototype`.

This prototype based flavor of OOP is very flexible but it became a source of confusion for programmers coming from class based languages. Several libraries were written to simulate classes. And finally they were added to the language in 2015.

This is the reason why a class is actually just a function in JavaScript.